# Lightning strike causes fast download?

Tags: internet-connection

Ok, REALLY strange question.

My friend says he was downloading a 14 GB file at about 1 mb/s when suddenly there was a lightning strike outside and momentarily the download speed jumped to 10,000,000 GB/s. The file finnished downloading.

He even has the screenshot to prove it. I also trust him and don't believe that he would be lying.

So my question is: how is this even possible?? Is there just the possibility that the file was about to finish downloading anyway and the lightning strike coincided with a freak download speed calculation error?

Comment: He has a screen shot of it? Is his name Flash? On a serious note, is the file downloaded any good. I would be inclined to believe it is corrupt.

Comment: *"how is this even possible?"* -- It's not possible or believeable.

Comment: why all the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible (non-lying) way this can happen is if whatever software your friend was using does not handle interrupted downloads well.

If there was a large amount of data left and the lightning strike took down your friends internet the program he was using could have mistakenly thought the download was "Done". So the speed calulator seeing your progress instantly jumping from maybe 1 GB to "Done" it decided to take size of the jump as "progress"

After that it is just a matter of dividing a big number (13 GB of progress) by a tiny number (1.3 microseconds) which gives you a huge number (10,000,000 GB/s).

But honestly, I think [ultasawblade's answer](https://superuser.com/a/800828/25625) is more likely.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is the answer I was looking for. Some way the computer could have miscalculated so fantastically. I know this is possible since I have had my battery meter say that I had 105 hours left.

Answer (score 4):

> So my question is: how is this even possible??

This is easily achieved by doing the following:

- Start a download
- Make the download window visible
- Press the PrtSc key
- Open up MS Paint by pressing the Windows key + R, then type `mspaint` and press ENTER
- Press CTRL-V
- Click "Select" on the ribbon, then "Rectangular Selection" from the drop down
- Precisely draw a rectangle around the download window within the image, then press Crop
- Where the download speed is shown in the image, use the "Rectangular Selection" tool to copy and paste numbers in the area until a quantity of around 10,000,000 GB/s is shown.  You may need to use the text tool to generate other numbers and the G in GB.
- Save the screenshot

You'll then have a screenshot displaying a speed of 10,000,000 GB/s.  It may take some practice to get it to look like the official download window, but certainly possible.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, but as I said, I am almost certain that my friend is NOT lying, which I thought I had made clear in the question